# Integrating antd with react-boilerplate

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-boilerplate, antd

I added this to the production config:

```
babelQuery: {
    plugins: [["import", { libraryName: "antd", style: true }]],
  },
```

but I'm still getting errors like `ReferenceError: Menu is not defined.` Am I missing something? Everything works fine locally when I add the same to the dev config so I'm a little confused.

Comment: Will need way more info. How are you importing in the files themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently having the exact same problem. So I'll add the extra info here.

I too the information from the following page to setup the ant-design kit:
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-with-create-react-app

The webpack.dev.babel contains the following babelQuery and is working fine:

```
babelQuery: {
    presets: ['babel-preset-react-hmre'].map(require.resolve),
    plugins: [['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }]],
},
```

The development environment runs fine.

But, when adding the same plugins configuration to the webpack.prod.babel like this:

```
babelQuery: {
    plugins: [['import', { libraryName: 'antd', style: true }]],
},
```

I'm getting the error like @userinev when loading the page after running the production build.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Menu is not defined
```

It's having issues with loading the first component that gets loaded from the antd library.

When removing the plugins configuration from the prod-config, the app is loading, but the styling is missing.

**UPDATE:**
The dot (.) in Menu.Item is the problem in the production-build. 
The workaround is to create an 'alias', like

```
const Item = Menu.Item;
```

See: https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5060#issuecomment-283339199

Comment: It seems to be an issue with the Menu component of antd. When using the internally used RcMenu, it's working fine even in production-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can **remove** the boilerplate's including on package.json of the babel plugin that causes error:

Delete this:
"plugins": [
       "transform-react-inline-elements"
     ]